# How to keep node from moving off of (outside of) another node

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, sknode

I have a few square-shaped nodes (like floor tiles) going along the screen and I'd like to restrict my player (P) node to moving within these nodes.

```
---------------------------------
|   | P |   |   |   |   |   |   |    <- Want no movement allowed 
---------------------------------       outside of these squares.
            |   |
        -------------
        |   |   |   | ...  
        -------------
```

I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to do this with SpriteKit Physics, that doesn't involve putting invisible blocks all the way around the floor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An `SKConstraint` object describes a mathematical constraint on a node’s position or orientation.

You can use `SKConstraint` to keep a node a certain distance from a specific point in horizontal axis:

```
let center = size.width/2.0, difference = CGFloat(170.0)
let leftConstraint = SKConstraint.positionX(SKRange(constantValue: center - difference))
let rightConstraint = SKConstraint.positionX(SKRange(constantValue: center + difference))    
player.constraints = [leftConstraint, rightConstraint]
```

You can also decide to enable or disable a certain constraint during the game:

```
leftConstraint.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You use edge based physics bodies, not volume based physics bodies.  So in your construction of the physics body, look for anything with `edge` in the constructor.  Now, if you want to be able to walk between the tiles, you will have to create 1 physics body for the outer wall of your floor, because doing it tile by tile will mean you will be stuck in individual tiles.